# Dual Boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, 14.04

This is my first time trying to install ubuntu. I have a flash drive that will boot to the installation. But once I egg there it says it can't find an os on the computer. What do I do?

Comment: Did you turn off fast boot and disable secure boot?

Comment: Do you have Windows already installed?

Comment: Yes I have windows installes

Answer (score 0):

Press a key when start up your computer and check if there are any options for you to get into systems like "widows load manager" or "ubuntu".

I guess your windows system is under UEFI mode and your ubuntu should also be installed under this mode.

If that is the case, check your bios to see if your computer is booting under UEFI mode. If you choose legacy, the problem you described is likely to happen.

Also if you are using a RAID with any ssd caching technology like intel rst,, just turn that off.